# How to handle the pound sign ('#') in filenames?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem when it comes to filenames in Node.js where some incoming files have the pound sign `#` which causes problems when working with the file system and then using a URL spawned from the filename to reaccess it in an `<img>` tag.

```
var fileDir = "/foo/bar#s.png/";
var dirContents = fs.readdirSync(fileDir);

document.getElementById("id1").src = encodeURIComponent(path.join('cache', fileDir, dirContents[0]))
// %2Fcache%2Ffoo%2Fbar%23s.png%2Fbar%23s%2001.png :: Broken img

document.getElementById("id2").src = path.join('cache', fileDir, dirContents[1])
// /cache/foo/bar#s.png/bar#s 02.png :: Also broken img
```

I have control over the directory names, but the final file `.png`s are up to the user who loaded the file.  How do I go about handling these characters?

Comment: Obviously filenames used in an URL can't have the pound sign in them, as it would be interpreted as the URL hash. You have to change the way you're spawning the URL's to the images, or even better, change the filenames.

Comment: Get the upstream process that's giving you these filenames that are incompatible with both the file system and URLs to stop doing that.  Life does not need to be that complicated, so rather than working around it, I'd suggest removing the complication in the first place.

Comment: The files are being created from extracting archives.  The directory name is based on the original file name, and the extracted files are the ones causing the problem.  Do I need to create some sort of renaming function that will rename each of `dirContents[i]` files if a `#` is found?  It might be a solution, but I am hoping for something simpler.

Comment: @ms_nitrogen Not "some sort of renaming function", just use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @Bergi: I tried it in the example above and it still led to broken img tags.

Comment: @ms_nitrogen: You have to call it on the file/directory name only of course, not on the whole path

Comment: Okay, I'll try it out when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would [escape these characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

```
document.getElementById("id1").src = path.join('cache',
                                               ...fileDir.split("/").map(encodeURIComponent),
                                               encodeURIComponent(dirContents[0]));
```

However, you will need to make sure that your server properly decodes them again when receiving the image request, not all implementations agree on what to do with percent encoding in file paths. An easier an possibly better approach is to prevent these characters from occurring in file names in the first place.

Comment: Stopping the files would be ideal, but I don't think it is possible.  It is going to be a stand alone `electron` application, and when you're loading in a file, and the program refuses until you rename the file and it's contents is more of a hassle for the end user than is really necessary.

Thanks for the function!  I'll put it to good use.